# Laravel project running on development machine gives this error after "This site is not secure error" after windows update

Tags: laravel

I have been running my laravel project for a while in Edge on my local machine. However after a Windows update last nightI am getting the following error when I try to run my application in Edge -"This site is not secure" and in the details the following 
Your PC doesn't trust this websites security certificate. 
The host name in the websites security certificate differs from the website you are trying to visit.
Error code DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA
DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID
Because this site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security, you cannot continue to this site at this time.

Could someone please help. I have spent the whole day working on this and I am near the end of my project.

Comment: Some browsers hate Laravel's self-signed SSL certificates ( Firefox, Edge, etc.). Try downloading Chrome. If that doesn't work for you, try adding this to the bottom of your routes/web.php file URL::forceScheme('http');

Comment: My application was not being served when I typed myapplication.dev in the URL. I eventually got around this by running php artisan serve. This allowed me to run the application from http://127.0.0.1:8000